# Custom Formly Component not showing validation message on blur

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I have a custom angular date picker component which uses ngb-datepicker and implements control value accessor. Now I create a formly component from this to use in my json form. This works fine but it's not showing validation message when user clicks in control and clicks away. The control just stays untouched even though it was touched. It's like blur is not triggered. What I am missing here?

**Custom date picker control**

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-date-picker',
  template: `
  <div class="input-group">
  <input
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
    name="dp"
    [formControl]="myControl"
    ngbDatepicker
    #d="ngbDatepicker"
    (keyup)="change($event)"
    (dateSelect)="change($event)"
  />
  <button
    class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3"
    (click)="d.toggle()"
    type="button"
  ></button>
</div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NgbdDatepickerPopup),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup implements ControlValueAccessor {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  model = '';
  private _onChange = (value: unknown) => {};
  private _onTouch = (value: unknown) => {};

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.myControl.setValue(obj);
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._onTouch = fn;
  }

  change(event: unknown) {
    if (event instanceof Event) {
      const date = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
      this._onChange(date);
      this._onTouch(date);
    }
  }
}
```

**Formly Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-field-input',
 template: `
   <custom-date-picker [formControl]="formControl" [formlyAttributes]="field"></custom-date-picker>
   <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">
            <formly-validation-message *ngIf="showError" [field]="field"></formly-validation-message>
    </div>
 `,
})
export class FormlyFieldInput extends FieldType {}
```

Comment: I think that is: `_onTouched = () => {};` -onTouched has no arguments-. BTW check if really is touched writting in your .html `{{formControl.touched}}`

Comment: It's false. It's like no blur event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by making _onTouch public and updating the template for `custom-date-picker` to bind to the blur event (blur)="_onTouch($event)".